# Converting From U+ unicode string definition to true unicode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have a long list of unicode definitions and description mappings that use the `'U+1F49A'` coding convention.

In python (3), how can I read these in as true unicode characters? (i.e. `'\u00001F49A'` or ''

I've tried array slicing and composition eg `'\U000{}'.format('1F49A')` but end up with `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape` as the initial string instantiation craps out on a partial unicode declaration.

Comment: The answer below is what you want, but if you're curious about how to use the `\U` representation, look for `unicode_escape`. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+unicode_escape

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to parse the number, and [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to convert the number to a single-character string.

For example:

```
In [8]: chr(0x1f49a)
Out[8]: ''

In [9]: s='U+1F49A'

In [10]: chr(int(s[2:], 16))
Out[10]: ''
```

If you want to convert all of the `U+xxxx` instances in a larger string, you can use the same `chr()`/`int()` pattern in the 2nd arg of [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
In [14]: s = 'U+1F49A -vs- U+2764'

In [15]: re.sub(r'U\+([0-9a-fA-F]+)', lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)), s)
Out[15]: ' -vs- ❤'
```

Comment: Do these commands need to be in a Jupyter notebook? `chr()` and `unichr()` fail at the command-line: `chr(0x1f49a)` gives `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)` and `unichr(0x1f49a)` gives `ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)`.

Comment: @mmorin - No, Jupyter is not required, but Python3 is.  Those commands work well in Python3 on Ubuntu, at least.